# DATASTAX OPSCENTER 6.0 not able to connect to DSE 4.8 cluster

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am trying to connect opscenter to DSE cluster, I tried and verified the same configurations with in the other environments (DEV, STAGING) but while I am trying to do the same on Prod, I am getting these error on agent.log file

```
INFO [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:24,728 Starting system.
INFO [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:24,730 Starting 
JMXComponent
WARN [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:24,732 Exception while 
processing JMX data: java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication 
failed! Credentials required
ERROR [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:24,732 Security failure 
connecting to JMX: Authentication failed! Credentials required
INFO [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:24,733 Starting 
StompComponent
INFO [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:24,733 SSL communication is 
disabled
INFO [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:24,733 Creating stomp 
connection to x.y.z.x:61620
ERROR [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:24,736 Dec 14, 2017 
6:29:24 PM org.jgroups.client.StompConnection connect
INFO: Connected to x.y.z.x:1234

WARN [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:29,738 Attempted to ping 
opscenterd on stomp but did not receive a reply in time, will retry 
again later.
ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2017-12-14 18:29:29,740 Dec 14, 2017 
6:29:29 PM org.jgroups.client.StompConnection run
SEVERE: JGRP000112: Connection closed unexpectedly:
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:224)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
at org.jgroups.util.Util.readLine(Util.java:2825)
at org.jgroups.protocols.STOMP.readFrame(STOMP.java:240)
at org.jgroups.client.StompConnection.run(StompConnection.java:274)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


INFO [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:29,742 Starting 
JMXComponent
WARN [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:29,744 Exception while 
processing JMX data: java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication 
failed! Credentials required
ERROR [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:29,744 Security failure 
connecting to JMX: Authentication failed! Credentials required
INFO [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:29,744 Starting 
JMXComponent
WARN [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:29,746 Exception while 
processing JMX data: java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication 
failed! Credentials required
ERROR [async-dispatch-64] 2017-12-14 18:29:29,746 Security failure 
connecting to JMX: Authentication failed! Credentials required
```

Also the opscenterd.log show no errors for the cluster.

The configuration that i used are below.
I have used address.yaml

```
stomp_interface: x.x.x.x
use_ssl: 0
metrics_enabled: 1
hosts: [x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x]
storage_keyspace: opscenter_abc
```

cluster_name.conf

```
[jmx]
port = 7199
password = abc
username = abc

[cassandra]
seed_hosts = x.x.x.x , x.x.x.x , x.x.x.x 
api_port = 9160
cql_port = 9042
password = abc
username = fabe

[storage_cassandra]
seed_hosts = x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x
api_port = 9160
cql_port = 9042
keyspace = opscenter_abc

[cassandra_metrics]
5min_ttl = 2419200

[cluster_display_options]
display_name = badkfj
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Any help will be appreciated.